# Access Global variable from a .js file

Tags: javascript

HTML file :

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>

  <Title>Testing</Title>
 </HEAD>
   <Body>
 <script src="Test.js" language="JavaScript" type="Text/JavaScript" >
      CreateVariables();
 document.write(glVarMsg3);

</script>

</Body>

</HTML>
```

.js file:

```
function CreateVariables()
glVarMsg3="Global variable";
```

Friends please inform me what is the issue in this script? why i can't be able to access variable from .js file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, that's invalid syntax for declaring a function. You need braces:

```
function CreateVariables() {
    glVarMsg3="Global variable";
}
```

Secondly you can either set an `src` or script content, but not both. So you'd need:

```
<script src="Test.js"></script>
<script>
    CreateVariables();
    console.log(glVarMsg3);
</script>
```

A good place to start would be this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) on functions. Additionally, I hope this is just for learning/testing as the use of `document.write` and global variables in this way is discouraged.

Comment: Still this is no calling the Variable :-(

Comment: That's because if you declare a variable inside a function it's a local variable.

Comment: @ravb79 No. Declared without a `var`, it's implicitly declared at global scope. Please see updated answer

Comment: Okay, but shouldn't you just always use var when declaring a variable, as in from a best practice standpoint?

Comment: @ravb79 Depends on the requirements, but generally yes - as highlighted in the last sentence in my answer.

Comment: hmmm.. so we local variable always uses inside the function? and Global both? inside and anywhere?

Comment: @user3148414 Correct. But beware, if you use a third-party plugin which also defines a variable called `glVarMsg3`, yours could get overwritten. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Answer (score 1):

Just define your variables in global.js outside a function scope:

// global.js

```
var global1 = "I'm a global!";
var global2 = "So am I!";
```

// other js-file

```
function testGlobal () {
    alert(global1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first just import

```
<script src="Test.js">
</script>
```

after use

```
<script>
   CreateVariables();
   document.write(glVarMsg3);
</script>
```